# JTextField Limit Character

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtextfield

I have a JTextField named for Reservation ID on JFrame connected to MySQL database. 
Whenever I add a new passenger in the database, the JTextField should automatically generate a new Reservation ID for me in the JTextField based on an auto increment before I enter the passenger names and other details in the other textfields.

My code:

```
    resId = new JTextField();
    try{
        rs = stt.executeQuery("select ReservID as last_id from passenger");
        int lastid = rs.getInt("last_id");
        lastid++;
        resId.setText(String.valueOf(last_id));

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cannot retrieve");
    }
    resId.setBounds(432, 178, 126, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(resId);
    resId.setColumns(10);
```

The last row of my column RevervID has value of 003. When I run the form, it should display me **004** in the Reservation ID textfield How do I achieve that ? Please help..
Thanks

The texfield in the image link below
http://i.imgbox.com/wcf9KicU.png

Comment: get the last reservation id from the database.. then display it on your Jtexfield but increment the id first before you set it to the textfield.

Comment: How to achieve that ?

Comment: Assume that the Id is not editable the user, I'd might be tempted not to display it, especially if you're using some kind of auto keying mechanism for the table, but that's just me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out the maximum id using database query-> `Select max(id) from mytable`

Store the maximum id in a variable-> `int max_id= max_id_from_database;`

Increment `max_id` by one-> `max_id++;`

add max_id value to your JTextField-> `myJTextField.setText("" + max_id);`

Edited: According to your code (just add max before ReservID and add rs.next() in a if condition and ReservID must be integer in your database).

```
 resId = new JTextField();
    try{
        rs = stt.executeQuery("select max(ReservID) as last_id from passenger");
        if(rs.next()){
        int lastid = rs.getInt("last_id");
        lastid++;
        resId.setText(String.valueOf(last_id));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cannot retrieve");
    }
```